# How do you actually manipulate raw meat safely?

Tags: food-safety, raw-meat

I understand the need for hand-washing and food safety procedures. What I don't understand is how you physically manipulate raw meat while maintaining safety. For example, if I'm roasting a chicken, I need to unwrap the bird, put it on the cutting board, blot it dry, salt and pepper it (thus handling loose salt and the pepper grinder while also turning the bird, holding the body cavity open, etc.), and put it on the roasting pan. It feels like I need to stop every ten seconds to wash my hands, but that can't be right, can it? If nothing else, the precariousness of balancing a chicken on its shoulders while holding the cavity open with one hand so I can pour salt in with my untainted other hand just seems wrong.

So: how do you safely manipulate raw meat?

Comment: I like to either make a spice mixture before that I will throw out afterwords. Or use one hand for the meat one for the spices.

Comment: @mroll that sounds like an answer.

Comment: Raw chicken is a huge source of salmonella contamination! You are right to be concerned. Salt is a preservative that helps to kill bacteria along with act of cooking it. Really want you want to avoid is contaminating the rest of the kitchen.  Minimize rinsing in the sink. FDA says to just cook it as is w/out rinsing to avoid sink contamination. If you have another roasting pan you can prep in  that will need to be bleached and washed. You can put down newspaper on your counter tops. You should use a disinfectant bleach spray for the countertops and sink when done. Wear gloves